# CloudBuild Bash-style string manipulation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I need to extract a string from the TAG_NAME default variable. but i could not get this to work.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  id: find-folder-name
  dir: ${_DIR}
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      if [ ${_STRATEGY} = "tag" ]; echo "tag name " $TAG_NAME; echo ${TAG_NAME%\.np\.v\.*};fi
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
  secretEnv: ['GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY']
```

The regex works perfect fine if i just run it in gitbash locally.
The output is follow, i am expecting it will also print "test" as well, but it is empty. here is the output

```
tag name  test.np.v.1.1.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by assigning to a variable

```
release=$TAG_NAME;echo ${release%\.np\.v\.*}
```

Comment: Please, consider marking your answer as correct https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer